React - some image urls not loading in localhost env
In my website I use images from the web with backgroundImage
<div onClick={doSomething()} className="ProductImage" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${product.imageUrls[imageIndex]})`}}></div>

In production, all the images loads and visible as it should be, but when I run the website locally some of the images are not loaded.
for example:

I created local certificates and open localhost via HTTPS with:
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.crt&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=cert.key&&react-scripts start"

The images are under HTTPS, in a different domain but all of them are in the same server.
There are no console errors of any kind and it only happens when I run in localhost.
Any idea how I can fix that?
Thanks!
